# How to fetch the last item in a JSON in C#

Tags: c#, rest, foreach, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to get a single value out of a JSON response from Azure Rest API.

Below is my code where I was able to get to final array but unable to fetch the last item from this array.

```
            string token = await GetAccessToken(GMETenantID, GMEClientID, GMEAppKey);

            var httpClient = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/")
            };
            string URI = $"/subscriptions/{SubscriptionGUID}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts?api-version=2019-06-01";

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(URI).ConfigureAwait(false);

            var HttpsResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dynamic Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(HttpsResponse);

            foreach (dynamic item in Result["value"])
            {
                string StorageID = item.id;
                string StorageAccountName = item.name;
                string ResourceType = item.type;

                int CharsToRemove = 12 + ResourceType.Length + StorageAccountName.Length;

                string ResourceGroupName = StorageID.Remove(0,67);
                ResourceGroupName = ResourceGroupName.Remove(ResourceGroupName.Length - CharsToRemove);

                string StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss") + "Z"; ;
                string EndTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss") + "Z";

                var BlobhttpClient = new HttpClient
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/")
                };

                string BlobURI = $"/subscriptions/{SubscriptionGUID}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroupName}/providers/{ResourceType}/{StorageAccountName}/blobServices/default/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?timespan={StartTime}/{EndTime}&aggregation=average&metricnames=BlobCapacity&api-version=2018-01-01";
                BlobhttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
                BlobhttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                HttpResponseMessage Blobresponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(BlobURI).ConfigureAwait(false);
                var BlobHttpsResponse = await Blobresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                dynamic value = JObject.Parse(BlobHttpsResponse);

                foreach (dynamic List1 in value["value"])
                {
                    foreach (dynamic List2 in List1["timeseries"])
                    {
                        foreach (dynamic List3 in List2["data"])
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine((long?)List3["average"]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

I also feel there must be an easier way to get this one value out instead of using 3 Foreach loops.

HttpsResponse: (There are a 168 timestamp and average values in the actual response but i've put only 3 values)

```
{
  "cost": 0,
  "timespan": "2020-05-22T03:04:46Z/2020-05-29T03:04:46Z",
  "interval": "PT1H",
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/MyAstorageAccountName/blobServices/default/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/BlobCapacity",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
      "name": {
        "value": "BlobCapacity",
        "localizedValue": "Blob Capacity"
      },
      "displayDescription": "The amount of storage used by the storage account's Blob service in bytes.",
      "unit": "Bytes",
      ".timeseries": [
        {
          "metadatavalues": [],
          "data": [
            {
              "timeStamp": "2020-05-22T03:04:00Z",
              "average": 586904516140.0
            },
            {
              "timeStamp": "2020-05-22T04:04:00Z",
              "average": 587058965680.0
            },
            {
              "timeStamp": "2020-05-22T05:04:00Z",
              "average": 587058965680.0
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "errorCode": "Success"
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices",
  "resourceregion": "eastus2"
}
```

All I want is the number 587058965680 which is the last value of the JSON and the most recent timestamp.

Pretty much I want to get exact result the way I'm getting in below powershell code
PowerShell works like a charm in 4 lines but I had to write so many lines in C#

```
$StorageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "My ResourceGroupName"

$StorageAccountID = $StorageAccounts.ID + "/blobServices/default"
$Start = (get-date).AddDays(-7)
$End = get-date

$Metric = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $StorageAccountID -MetricName "BlobCapacity" -StartTime $Start -EndTime $End  -WarningAction Ignore

$ContainerSize = ($Metric.Data | sort-object -Descending Average | Select-Object -First 1).Average/1024/1024/1024
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow solved it using a weird logic :)

```html
string token = await GetAccessToken(GMETenantID, GMEClientID, GMEAppKey);

            var httpClient = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/")
            };
            string URI = $"/subscriptions/{SubscriptionGUID}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts?api-version=2019-06-01";

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(URI).ConfigureAwait(false);

            var HttpsResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dynamic Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(HttpsResponse);

            foreach (dynamic item in Result["value"])
            {
                string StorageID = item.id;
                string StorageAccountName = item.name;
                string ResourceType = item.type;

                int CharsToRemove = 12 + ResourceType.Length + StorageAccountName.Length;

                string ResourceGroupName = StorageID.Remove(0,67);
                ResourceGroupName = ResourceGroupName.Remove(ResourceGroupName.Length - CharsToRemove);

                string StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss") + "Z"; ;
                string EndTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss") + "Z";

                var BlobhttpClient = new HttpClient
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/")
                };

                string BlobURI = $"/subscriptions/{SubscriptionGUID}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroupName}/providers/{ResourceType}/{StorageAccountName}/blobServices/default/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?timespan={StartTime}/{EndTime}&aggregation=average&metricnames=BlobCapacity&api-version=2018-01-01";
                BlobhttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
                BlobhttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                HttpResponseMessage Blobresponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(BlobURI).ConfigureAwait(false);
                var BlobHttpsResponse = await Blobresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                dynamic value = JObject.Parse(BlobHttpsResponse);
                long FinalValue = 0;
                foreach (dynamic List1 in value["value"])
                {
                    foreach (dynamic List2 in List1["timeseries"])
                    {
                        foreach (dynamic List3 in List2["data"])
                        {                            
                            if (List3["average"] != null)
                            {
                                long NewData = List3["average"];
                                
                                if (NewData > FinalValue)
                                {
                                    FinalValue = NewData;
                                }
                                else if (NewData > FinalValue)
                                {
                                    FinalValue = NewData;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(""); 
                Console.WriteLine(FinalValue);
                Console.WriteLine($"Done with StorageAccount: {StorageAccountName}");                
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple model for it :

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("timeStamp")]
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("average")]
    public decimal Average { get; set; }
}
```

Now, just use `JObject` to navigate to the `data` key in the json, and deserilize it.

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
var data = jObj["value"][0][".timeseries"][0]["data"].ToString();
var dataList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Data>>(data);
```

Then, you can use Linq to get the last element in the array :

```
var last = dataList.Last();
```

If you don't want to use `Models`, you can have a direct access to the values using `JObject`

So, you can do this directly :

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
var data = jObj["value"][0][".timeseries"][0]["data"].Last();
var avg = data["average"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` might be helpful for this particular case.

For example:

```cs
IList<long> averages = 
    value["value"].SelectMany(val => val[".timeseries"]
                  .SelectMany(tm => tm["data"]
                  .Select(ave => (long) ave["average"]))).ToList();
```

Outputs:

```cs
[0] 586904516140
[1] 587058965680
[2] 587058965680
```