# How to read just (for example) last n items in a json file by c#?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I want to read just (for example) last n items in my chat.json file. How is it possible? By now I can just read all json content. I meant I want something like pagination to prevent process time.

My example json:

```
[

  {
    "ChatId": "e4b4d5c940df45579e01bf15f5074127",
    "From": "user1",
    "SessionTime": "2023-12-14T06:39:20.8549695+03:30",
    "Message": "hi"
  },
  {
    "ChatId": "93f4b8d45d56429cb9d03c1b6fff860c",
    "From": "user2",
    "SessionTime": "2023-12-14T06:39:31.2709073+03:30",
    "Message": "hello"
  },

  {
    "ChatId": "c795dc973e8745218c126c308df90a2a",
    "From": "user2",
    "SessionTime": "2023-12-14T06:41:44.7302957+03:30",
    "Message": "are you fine?"
  },
]
```

My code to read from json and return the list of items:

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Chat>>? GetAllChats(int items = 10)
 {
     var rootPath = _appEnvironment.WebRootPath;
     var jsonPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, "json/chat.json");
     var data = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(jsonPath);
     var chats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Chat>>(data);

     return chats.ToList();
 }
```

I don't want to use `ReadAllTextAsync()` method, but read just last 10 items for example.

Comment: I think you need to deserialize your (complete) JSON (like is done in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62097187/724039) Because just getting the last n items is (AFAIK) not possible.

Comment: How would know which were the last 10 items without reading all the items first?

Comment: maybe something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452902/how-to-read-a-text-file-reversely-with-iterator-in-c-sharp - and occasionally check if it valid json and then parse it

Comment: If I had to do it: I'd consider switching to [jsonlines](https://jsonlines.org/) _or_ (and probably I'd end up with) I'd use a Single-File local DB (SQLite, LiteDB, ...) instead of text files, where you could query with more sophistication.

Comment: I'd suggest to check if you really need to read the files backwards. If the files are so big that it takes too long to read with e.g. System.Text.Json, you might consider storing your data in multiple smaller files or use a database (e.g. time series) instead of json files. 
Order shouldn't matter anyway, since JSON doesn't enforce any order of its items, so relying on an order in a JSON file seems to be a design flaw.

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't output to a text file, but to a DB.  Assuming you have no control over that, you might consider reading the file line by line with a streamreader and writing those entries to a DB table or an array of a standard Class Object.  Then you can sort by SessionTime and use LIMIT in a LINQ/SQL statement.